# Writing Derived Class Members to Binary File

Tags: c++, function, oop, inheritance, file-io

I am working on a school-management-system command line interface application. First, let me try to explain how's my program is designed and what I am trying to achieve.

**My present program design:**
I have three classes viz. `Student`, `Teacher` and `Staff`. All three classes are inherited from class `SchoolMember` publicly. `SchoolMember` has data members `int id` and `char name[30]`. `Student`, `Teacher` and `Staff` has some additional data members and member functions.

I have three different functions `removeStudent()`, `removeTeacher()` and `removeStaff()` to remove contents of student, teacher and staff respectively from a binary file.
Here's how `removeTeacher()` looks like:

```
void removeTeacher()
{
  Teacher teacherRead;
  int inputTeacherId; 
  short flag = 0;
  ifstream fileToRead("data/teacher.dat", ios::binary);
  ofstream fileToWrite("data/temp_teacher.dat", ios::binary | ios::app);
  cout << "Enter ID of teacher whose data has to be removed: ";
  cin >> inputTeacherId;
  while (fileToRead.read((char *)&teacherRead, sizeof(teacherRead)))
  {
    if (inputTeacherId == teacherRead.getId())
      flag++;
    else
      fileToWrite.write((char *)&teacherRead, sizeof(teacherRead));
  }
  if (flag == 0)
    cout << "Sorry, No Match found.";
  else
    cout << "Data of teacher " << inputTeacherId << " has been removed from file.";
  fileToRead.close();
  fileToWrite.close();
  remove("data/teacher.dat");
  rename("data/temp_teacher.dat", "data/teacher.dat");
}
```

The `removeStudent()` and `removeStaff()` function is exactly same! The only difference is in object i.e. in `removeStudent()` `Student studentRead` is used and in `removeTeacher()` `Teacher teacherRead` is used and also, the file path is different.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Since the functionality of the three functions is the same. I want to replace it with one function. So, I searched the internet and read some inheritance and OOP concepts. Then I implemented a function:

```
void removeMember(string filePath, string tempFilePath, SchoolMember member)
{
  int inputId = 0; 
  short flag = 0;
  ifstream fileToRead(filePath.c_str(), ios::binary);
  ofstream fileToWrite(tempFilePath.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::app);
  cout << "Enter ID whose data has to be removed: "; 
  cin >> inputId;
  while (fileToRead.read((char *)&member, sizeof(member)))
  {
    if (inputId == member.getId())
      ++flag;
    else
      fileToWrite.write((char *)&member, sizeof(member));
  }
  if (flag == 0)
    cout << "Sorry, No Match found.";
  else
    cout << "Data of ID " << inputId << " has been removed from file.";
  fileToRead.close();
  fileToWrite.close();
  remove(filePath.c_str());
  rename(tempFilePath.c_str(), filePath.c_str());
}
```

Now, when I call the above function in:

```
void removeDataScreen()
{
  Student schoolStudent; // Object
  removeMember("data/student.dat", "data/temp_student.dat", schoolStudent);
}
```

Only `id` and `name` are removed from the `student.dat` file. All the data members of class `Student` ain't removed. I want to remove all the data members of the `Student`. how can that be achieved?

I hope I explained the issue in enough detail. I will be looking for solutions :)

Full source code can be found at: https://github.com/vkWeb/school-management-system/blob/master/main.cpp

Comment: This is object Slicing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: Also remember that sizeof() is a compile time constant.

Comment: I assume you don't know template functions yet?

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for guiding me to object slicing. I will read about it.  

sizeof() being a compile-time constant cause any issue?  


Yes, you're right I don't know about template functions. Will it help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular problem, template functions are well suited:

```
template <class T>
void removeMember(string filePath, string tempFilePath) {
    T MemberObject;
    // Rest of your code
}
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/